# How can I simulate touch gestures/events on a non-touchscreen monitor?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, simulation, simulator

I have a Unity-designed game which works with Windows 10 native touch gestures on some menus.
I really want to test out this game program on different aspects but doesn't have a touchscreen to test with.

Hence, I kindly ask here if there are any best methods to test the game's touch events in my computer without the use of a touchscreen. Maybe using a simulator that I can input touch feedback with mouse would be perfect. I found several methods online but some of them are outdated and not fitting into my question. Please help.

Comment: Did you search or do any research? I ran a quick search and Bing even suggested helpful terms that led me to this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-the-touch-using-the-mouse.54800/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to demonstrate the minimum necessary effort on the part of the asker.

Comment: music2myear, did you even bother to look at that link you shared? It's about unity on iPhone (the question is about Windows 10), and it mostly says it isn't supported. And then you have the gall to complain about low effort posting...